# Traveling to US to meet my fiancé

Tags: b1-b2-visas

My fiancé was a student last year when I applied visa from India and it got rejected. This year she is working and I am planning to apply again. I have a stable job, bank balance for the trip. Shall I just say that I am going on a trip with my fiancé who is already there for 15 days? Just mentioning the number of days myself so that visa officer doesn’t think I am staying forever. Please suggest.

Comment: Your fiance is already in the US working and you're going to visit her? Or your fiance is also visiting the US but you're not travelling together? It's a bit unclear what your situation is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should say that.

It is good idea to be honest when you're passing the interview. Your other alternative is lying or hiding the information - but the consular officers are trained to spot lies or digging out the suppressed information. And being caught in this might have far worse consequences than being rejected again.

However I also suggest to spend more time to prepare your case better, especially considering your past rejection. To qualify for the B1/2 visa you need to overcome the presumption of immigration intent. If your fiance is working in the US - as stated in comment it is a bit unclear - visiting her would actually **contribute** to the presumption of immigration intent, making your burden greater. Neither bank balance for the trip nor a stable job guarantees your return, so you need to bring more evidence which would overcome the presumption that you'd remain in USA.